# Why ui update when binding ItemsSource in xaml but doesn't when assigning it in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind a `combobox` having a `DataTemplate` to a list of classes generated by a static methode `Populate()`.

When assigning `combo1.ItemsSource = Peoplelist;` code-behinde, `combobox` items in ui are updating, but when I do a binding in xaml: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Peoplelist}"` it is not. What I am missing?

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<People> Peoplelist;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Peoplelist = new List<People>();
            People.Populate(Peoplelist);

            InitializeComponent();
            //combo1.ItemsSource = Peoplelist;  //working
        }
    }


    public class People
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public People() { }

        public People(String _FirstName, String _FamilyName)
        {
            FirstName = _FirstName;
            LastName = _FamilyName;
        }

        public static void Populate(List<People> lst)
        {
            lst.Add(new People
            {
                FirstName = "Jon",
                LastName = "Jonathan",
            });
            lst.Add(new People
            {
                FirstName = "Mark",
                LastName = "Markthan",
            });
            lst.Add(new People
            {
                FirstName = "Spence",
                LastName = "Spencer",
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
           mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="combo1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="200" 
          SelectedValuePath="LastName" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Peoplelist}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="--"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Note that `combo1.ItemsSource = Peoplelist;` is not a binding, but just an ordinary assignment.

Comment: better use Interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` . Will make life easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.
First: You didn't specify a data context in your xaml or code behind so it doesn't know where the data is that you want to bind to.
Second: Your Peoplelist should be a property because WPF data binding only works with public properties.

So your MainWindow class should be

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<People> Peoplelist { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Peoplelist = new List<People>();
        People.Populate(Peoplelist);
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Peoplelist should also be a readonly property. Otherwise it should fire a change notification. Declare it as `public List<People> Peoplelist { get; } = new List<People>();`

Comment: Or better `public ObservableCollection<People> Peoplelist { get; } = new ObservableCollection<People>();` to make any later additions or removals of elements  update the UI.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that. It eluded me because I searched for the way with the least changes to fix the code.

Comment: @Clemens thank you yea as you said it must be flexible, of course i have also to change populate methode: `public static void Populate(ObservableCollection<People> lst)`

Comment: @johan472 More flexible: `public static void Populate(ICollection<People> lst)`